# How to add the Where clause in PostgreSQL psycopg2 Python execute statement

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I'm trying to get the query to return a value but I get None!

```
        selectstatement = "SELECT * FROM customer Where (('ID' =" +"%s"
        data = 12345

        cursor.execute(selectstatement, (data,))
        records = cursor.fetchone()
        print(records[0])
```

Now I know it exists in the table but I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Desktop\EnterRegister.py", line 86, in <module>
    StartClean()
  File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Desktop\EnterRegister.py", line 28, in StartClean
    Analyze(DataReader)
  File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Desktop\EnterRegister.py", line 66, in Analyze
    print(records[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

If i do this:

```
selectstatement = "SELECT * FROM customer


cursor.execute(selectstatement)
records = cursor.fetchall()
```

I get all the results but I can't find the resource to specify the where clause perfectly.

Comment: Show the complete error message.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto 
 done its  the fact thta the table has the info but i cant seem to get the record i believe the way my execute query is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing the string `ID` to the passed value. This is the correct way:

```
selectstatement = "SELECT * FROM customer Where ID = %s"
```

But if the `ID` column name was created in upper case and wrapped in double quotes then it is necessary to always use double quotes:

```
selectstatement = '''SELECT * FROM customer Where "ID" = %s'''
```